# isset($_POST['submit']) not pass value when i use form for id

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="complete.php" id="formSubmit" class="formSubmit">
<!--my fields-->
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'/>
```

Here my complete.php page code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "submitted";
}else{
echo "not submit";
}
```

I'm getting "not submit" message when I use id="formSubmit" if i remove form id, I mean without form id I get submitted message

Comment: I can't reproduce that, it is working for me. What do you exacly mean by _...when I use id="formSubmit"_ ? Do you mean when you assign this id to the form or when you ask $_POST for the "formSubmit"?

Comment: Post request is triggered by input type "submit", but when you submit a form this field value is not submitted.

you have to create a new field (with type hidden if you dont want users to view it) and then set isset on the field name something like this.

<form method="post" action="complete.php" id="formSubmit" class="formSubmit">
<!--my fields-->
<input type='hidden' name='hiddenvalue' value='Register'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>

if (isset($_POST['hiddenvalue'])){
echo "submitted";
}else{
echo "not submit";
}

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahAli _“Post request is triggered by input type "submit", but when you submit a form this field value is not submitted.”_ - that is not true. (At least not for a _default_ form submission - if the data is serialized by JavaScript, then things might be different.)

Comment: Sounds like you might have some JavaScript, that submits the form via AJAX, and that gets bound to the form via that specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```js
<form method="post" action="complete.php" id="formSubmit" class="formSubmit">
<!--my fields-->
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'/>
```

Javascript code was there when form submit
condition was there
after my condition ok then submit my form

so there is no click event
form was submit through code.

So i changed form submit to click submit button when my conditions ok.